# Compiling C++ with MongoDB

Tags: c++, mongodb, compilation

I am getting bunch of error when i try to compile the C++ code to connect to MongoDB.

using command: directories refer to mongoclient lib and boost libs.

g++ tutorial.cpp -o tutorial -I/usr/include/mongo/client -L/usr/lib -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/

Any suggesttion how to fix the error

labuser@labuser:~/mDBTest$ g++ tutorial.cpp -I/usr/include/mongo/client -L/usr/lib -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/ -o tutorial
/tmp/cc9L7BCw.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
tutorial.cpp:(.text+0x23f): undefined reference to`boost::system::generic_category()'
tutorial.cpp:(.text+0x249): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
tutorial.cpp:(.text+0x253): undefined reference to`boost::system::system_category()'
/tmp/cc9L7BCw.o: In function `mongo::DBException::DBException(std::string const&, int)':
tutorial.cpp:(.text._ZN5mongo11DBExceptionC2ERKSsi[_ZN5mongo11DBExceptionC5ERKSsi]+0x17): undefined reference to`vtable for mongo::DBException'
tutorial.cpp:(.text._ZN5mongo11DBExceptionC2ERKSsi[_ZN5mongo11DBExceptionC5ERKSsi]+0x4c): undefined reference to `mongo::DBException::traceIfNeeded(mongo::DBException const&)'
/tmp/cc9L7BCw.o: In function`mongo::DBException::~DBException()':
tutorial.cpp:(.text._ZN5mongo11DBExceptionD2Ev[_ZN5mongo11DBExceptionD5Ev]+0xd): undefined reference to `vtable for mongo::DBException'
/tmp/cc9L7BCw.o: In function`mongo::UserException::UserException(int, std::string const&)':
tutorial.cpp:(.text._ZN5mongo13UserExceptionC2EiRKSs[_ZN5mongo13UserExceptionC5EiRKSs]+0x24): undefined reference to `vtable for mongo::UserException'
/tmp/cc9L7BCw.o: In function`mongo::HostAndPort::init(char const*)':
tutorial.cpp:(.text._ZN5mongo11HostAndPort4initEPKc[_ZN5mongo11HostAndPort4initEPKc]+0x29): undefined reference to `mongo::msgasserted(int, char const*)'
tutorial.cpp:(.text._ZN5mongo11HostAndPort4initEPKc[_ZN5mongo11HostAndPort4initEPKc]+0x7c): undefined reference to`mongo::msgasserted(int, char const*)'
/tmp/cc9L7BCw.o: In function `mongo::DBConnector::recv(mongo::Message&)':
tutorial.cpp:(.text._ZN5mongo11DBConnector4recvERNS_7MessageE[_ZN5mongo11DBConnector4recvERNS_7MessageE]+0x1e): undefined reference to`mongo::verifyFailed(char const*, char const*, unsigned int)'
/tmp/cc9L7BCw.o: In function `mongo::DBClientInterface::~DBClientInterface()':
tutorial.cpp:(.text._ZN5mongo17DBClientInterfaceD2Ev[_ZN5mongo17DBClientInterfaceD5Ev]+0xb): undefined reference to`vtable for mongo::DBClientInterface'
/tmp/cc9L7BCw.o: In function `mongo::DBClientInterface::DBClientInterface()':
tutorial.cpp:(.text._ZN5mongo17DBClientInterfaceC2Ev[_ZN5mongo17DBClientInterfaceC5Ev]+0x16): undefined reference to`vtable for mongo::DBClientInterface'
/tmp/cc9L7BCw.o: In function `mongo::DBClientWithCommands::DBClientWithCommands()':
tutorial.cpp:(.text._ZN5mongo20DBClientWithCommandsC2Ev[_ZN5mongo20DBClientWithCommandsC5Ev]+0x17): undefined reference to`vtable for mongo::DBClientWithCommands'
/tmp/cc9L7BCw.o: In function `mongo::DBClientWithCommands::~DBClientWithCommands()':
tutorial.cpp:(.text._ZN5mongo20DBClientWithCommandsD2Ev[_ZN5mongo20DBClientWithCommandsD5Ev]+0xc): undefined reference to`vtable for mongo::DBClientWithCommands'
/tmp/cc9L7BCw.o: In function `mongo::DBClientBase::DBClientBase()':
tutorial.cpp:(.text._ZN5mongo12DBClientBaseC2Ev[_ZN5mongo12DBClientBaseC5Ev]+0x25): undefined reference to`vtable for mongo::DBClientBase'
tutorial.cpp:(.text._ZN5mongo12DBClientBaseC2Ev[_ZN5mongo12DBClientBaseC5Ev]+0x2f): undefined reference to `vtable for mongo::DBClientBase'
tutorial.cpp:(.text._ZN5mongo12DBClientBaseC2Ev[_ZN5mongo12DBClientBaseC5Ev]+0x50): undefined reference to`mongo::DBClientBase::ConnectionIdSequence'
/tmp/cc9L7BCw.o: In function `mongo::UserException::~UserException()':
tutorial.cpp:(.text._ZN5mongo13UserExceptionD2Ev[_ZN5mongo13UserExceptionD5Ev]+0xb): undefined reference to`vtable for mongo::UserException'
/tmp/cc9L7BCw.o: In function `mongo::DBClientBase::~DBClientBase()':
tutorial.cpp:(.text._ZN5mongo12DBClientBaseD2Ev[_ZN5mongo12DBClientBaseD5Ev]+0xb): undefined reference to`vtable for mongo::DBClientBase'
tutorial.cpp:(.text._ZN5mongo12DBClientBaseD2Ev[_ZN5mongo12DBClientBaseD5Ev]+0x15): undefined reference to `vtable for mongo::DBClientBase'
/tmp/cc9L7BCw.o: In function`mongo::DBClientConnection::DBClientConnection(bool, mongo::DBClientReplicaSet*, double)':
tutorial.cpp:(.text._ZN5mongo18DBClientConnectionC2EbPNS_18DBClientReplicaSetEd[_ZN5mongo18DBClientConnectionC5EbPNS_18DBClientReplicaSetEd]+0x29): undefined reference to `vtable for mongo::DBClientConnection'
tutorial.cpp:(.text._ZN5mongo18DBClientConnectionC2EbPNS_18DBClientReplicaSetEd[_ZN5mongo18DBClientConnectionC5EbPNS_18DBClientReplicaSetEd]+0x33): undefined reference to`vtable for mongo::DBClientConnection'
tutorial.cpp:(.text._ZN5mongo18DBClientConnectionC2EbPNS_18DBClientReplicaSetEd[_ZN5mongo18DBClientConnectionC5EbPNS_18DBClientReplicaSetEd]+0xc9): undefined reference to `mongo::DBClientConnection::_numConnections'
/tmp/cc9L7BCw.o: In function`mongo::DBClientConnection::~DBClientConnection()':
tutorial.cpp:(.text._ZN5mongo18DBClientConnectionD2Ev[_ZN5mongo18DBClientConnectionD5Ev]+0xc): undefined reference to `vtable for mongo::DBClientConnection'
tutorial.cpp:(.text._ZN5mongo18DBClientConnectionD2Ev[_ZN5mongo18DBClientConnectionD5Ev]+0x16): undefined reference to`vtable for mongo::DBClientConnection'
tutorial.cpp:(.text._ZN5mongo18DBClientConnectionD2Ev[_ZN5mongo18DBClientConnectionD5Ev]+0x29): undefined reference to `mongo::DBClientConnection::_numConnections'
/tmp/cc9L7BCw.o:(.gcc_except_table+0x38): undefined reference to`typeinfo for mongo::DBException'
/tmp/cc9L7BCw.o:(.rodata._ZTVN5mongo16ConnectExceptionE[_ZTVN5mongo16ConnectExceptionE]+0x18): undefined reference to `mongo::UserException::appendPrefix(std::basic_stringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&) const'
/tmp/cc9L7BCw.o:(.rodata._ZTVN5mongo16ConnectExceptionE[_ZTVN5mongo16ConnectExceptionE]+0x20): undefined reference to`mongo::DBException::toString() const'
/tmp/cc9L7BCw.o:(.rodata._ZTVN5mongo18AssertionExceptionE[_ZTVN5mongo18AssertionExceptionE]+0x20): undefined reference to `mongo::DBException::toString() const'
/tmp/cc9L7BCw.o:(.rodata._ZTIN5mongo16ConnectExceptionE[_ZTIN5mongo16ConnectExceptionE]+0x8): undefined reference to`typeinfo for mongo::UserException'
/tmp/cc9L7BCw.o:(.rodata._ZTIN5mongo18AssertionExceptionE[_ZTIN5mongo18AssertionExceptionE]+0x8): undefined reference to `typeinfo for mongo::DBException'

Comment: As you see in https://mongodb-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-cpp-driver.html compile command must contain "-pthread -lmongoclient -lboost_thread-mt -lboost_filesystem -lboost_program_options -lboost_system".

Comment: Yes, I tried the method mentioned in the link and still same error.

Comment: May I ask how you found your way to that readthedocs.org link? It keeps turning up in SO questions and is absolutely nothing to do with the modern documentation for building the driver. Those docs can be found here: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/wiki/Tutorial. In particular, instructions on building the driver can be found here: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/wiki/Download-And-Compile-The-Legacy-Driver